# Is it possible to put a facebook 'like us' button on a craigslist posting?

Tags: facebook, gmail, facebook-like, craigslist

I am a business who frequently posts ads on Craigslist to draw new customers.  I've tried all the social plug-ins from the resources for posting a facebook like button/like box and when you post the ad with the recommended code, nothing appears on the ad itself.  I've also tried stealing the source code from another site's like button, but that didn't work either.  I don't yet have a website, so I am relying on craigslist traffic to build my facebook traffic.  Currently, I've had to settle with just posting a link to our facebook page, which doesn't require people to 'like' us.  The link is definitely working, as evidenced by the new traffic to our page, but the number of people who like us is only growing incrementally (we currently have 35 likes, yet 70 active monthly users.)

Additionally, I have a growing email list to which I send 'new arrivals' every week.  Is there any way to imbed a 'like' button within an gmail email message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craigslist doesnt allow embedding scripts/iframes which would be required for the Facebook like button.  You also cannot embed scripts/iframes into html emails so you could only provide a link.  However, you could create a Facebook reveal tab like [this one](https://www.facebook.com/teeseytees) which would require fans to like your page before they see the content.  The [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/) can show you how, or search on google.

Comment: Hugely helpful, thanks!  I'll stop banging my head trying to do the impossible, now that I know how to get around it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the actual like us button but what you could do is put a link to your Facebook business page and then people can like it from there.

For example:

```
<a href=" the link to your page"><img src="the facebooke image" /></a>
```

I do not think you would be able to use the actual widget code for craigslist because it requires javascript and craigslist ( i think could be wrong ) strips javascript out of a post when created.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes You can**
(1)Include the JavaScript SDK on your web page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.
This script uses the app ID of your app(web apps made in Facebook developer page)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=271360759562486";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

(2)Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

You can also change the button attribute as you want.

Comment: Craigslist doesn't let you embed scripts into posts.